# Display edges of a node on selection

Tags: graph, cytoscape.js

Currently, i send a request to a backend to get according edges of the selected node `Node-A` and Cytoscape displays them when received.

For the sake of performance and responsivity, it worth having all the edges for all the nodes preloaded but hidden until `Node-A` is selected by a user. Let's assume here nodes and edges aren't thousands.

Does Cytoscape work this way?